# Asymptotic relation of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} e^{-n^{\alpha} x}$ when $x \to 0$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, improper-integrals

Let be $f_n : x \mapsto e^{-n^{\alpha} x}$ with $\alpha > 0$.

Moreover, we define $g : x \mapsto \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} f_n(x)$ over $\mathbb{R}^{+}_{*}$.

This definition is valid because we can easily see that $g$ converges uniformly for all $a > 0$ over $[a, +\infty[$.

Eventually, as $f_n$ are $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ and due to uniform convergence of all derivatives (something of the form : $x \mapsto (-1)^p n^{-p\alpha} e^{-n^{\alpha} x}$) and simple convergence of $f_n$, $g$ is also $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$.

We can show for example that $g \sim e^{-x}$ when $x \to +\infty$ (by looking at the new function series $h_n : x \mapsto f_n(x)e^x$ and computing $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \lim_{n \to +\infty} h_n(x)$).

I wonder if we can find an asymptotic relation for $g$ when $x \to 0$.

To start, I showed that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^{+}} g(x) = +\infty$, because $g$ is decreasing and has no bounds.

I tried to compare $g$ to integrals and I have reached this inequality:

$\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{*}_{+}, \int_{1}^{+\infty} e^{-t^{\alpha} x} \textrm{d}t \leq f(x) \leq e^{-x} + \int_{1}^{+\infty} e^{-t^{\alpha} x} \textrm{d}t
\end{equation*}$

But I am unable to evaluate the integrals, hence I cannot conclude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

Let $F(x,\alpha)$ be defined as

$$F(x,\alpha)=\int_0^\infty e^{-xt^\alpha}\,dt$$

Then, enforcing the substitution $t=(u/x)^{1/\alpha}$ reveals

$$F(x,\alpha)=\frac1{\alpha x^\alpha}\underbrace{\int_0^\infty e^{-u}u^{\frac1\alpha-1}\,du}_{=\Gamma(1/\alpha)}$$

Finally, use the Euler-Maclaurin Summation Fromula.

Comment: Is there some more elementary way to derive the asymptotic relation rather than using the gamma function and Euler-MacLaurin Summation formula? I suspect there is, due to the fact this question was asked me in an oral examination context and I was not supposed to know about gamma / Euler-McLaurin stuff.

Comment: One does not need to know about either the EMSF or the Gamma function.  Note that from the integral test the sum is bounded as $$\int_1^\infty e^{-xt^\alpha}\,dt \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^\alpha x}\le e^{-x}+\int_1^\infty e^{-xt^\alpha}\,dt$$

Comment: I have written this inequality in my post, but I cannot deduce from it, an asymptotic relation, right?

Comment: You can deduce the asymptotic relationship.  Make the substitution as written in my solution and deduce the first term in the small $x$ expansion.

Comment: Could you just explain how do you deduce that the integral $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-u} u^{\frac{1}{\alpha - 1}} \textrm{d}u$ converges to a finite $C_{\alpha}$?

Comment: The integrand is $e^{-u}u^{\frac1\alpha -1}$.  So, for all $\alpha>0$, the term $\frac1\alpha -1>-1$ and the integral converges.